# VS Code works, but doesn't show me any controls to work with

Tags: visual-studio-code, user-interface, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and I've been faced with an issue in VS Code. When it starts it doesn't show me any control buttons or interface, just colored backround and that's it. But all the buttons works, I can press approximately the buttons I need and create a file, start editing and everything else.
Moreover it started suddenly, I've closed the window and it broke on next launch.

Here what I see:
[VS Code broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4XbO.png)

Help. please! I don't know how to fix it, I've been loking a lot of sites and it seems like nobody faced with this problem.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it? I suppose this could be caused by program file corruption. You could also try [starting with extensions disabled](/a/63158120/4518341) to see if that's the problem.

Comment: I've tried to reinstall, doesn't help. I'll try to run without extensions